# Count lines of a text file and show percentage of lines read (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

The program I have written does some calculations using values of a text file and printing the result. But in addition I want to see **how many percent of the text file it has gone through**.

My text file has 629 lines, so I want my program to count the lines, divide them by 629 and then multiply them by 100 and keep showing me how many percent of the total amount of lines it has already passed. But how do I do that?

I tried:

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('myfile.txt'))
percentage = 100*num_lines / 629
print percentage, '%'
```

But then it only returns me `'100%'` when it has gone through the entire text file already, but I want it to start at 0% and then progress to `100%`.

I am new to python and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: So, you want to know the number of lines in a file you just opened to parse?
This will be difficult without doing a separate pass of the file before, just to count the number of lines.
As the line change can be anywhere in the file, you have to search the whole file. An easier way would be to calculate the percentage of _bytes read_ vs the _filesize_. This can be done without an additional reading pass.

Answer (score 1):

To enhance @Peter Wood's answer

```
# get total lines of the input file
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

f = 'file.txt'
total = file_len(f)
num_lines = 0
for line in open(f):
    num_lines += 1
    percentage = 100 * num_lines / total
    print percentage, '%'
```